# Condition based iteration using for loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, vuejs2, iteration

I am trying to play audio file using for loop in vue.js. My code is like below

```
for(var i = this.start; i < this.end; i++) {
    var audio = new Audio('some value');
    audio.play();
    if(audio.ended == true) {
        //go for another iteration
    }
}
```

I would like to go for another iteration after the condition is true. Actually I would like to play audio file one after another.How can I do that ?

Comment: Wrap it in a function and have it call itself

Comment: Recursive functions

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something like this perhaps:

```
function audioPlayer(iteration = this.start) {  // iteration variable with default parameter
  if (iteration < this.end) {
    let audio = new Audio('some value');
    audio.play();
    if(audio.ended == true) {
        //go for another iteration
        this.audioPlayer(iteration + 1);
    }
  } else {
    return "end is reached";
  }
}
```

In this case you can use ES6's [`default parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). **Also**, if you use [`default parameters`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) you don't have to change any of your existing code(from where you have called this function as function signature is unchanged). As I don't know your exact code logic, I cannot help you with code. But, I hope this will point you in right direction. Please let me know if you still face any issues :)

Comment: Thanks @noobs. Actually I would like to play audio file one after another. I have to use iteration value `i` inside audio file src URL. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu updated my answer. Please let me know if you still face any issues implementing this.

Comment: Thanks @noobs. I am using this in a Vue.js method.

Comment: @abuabu did the solution helped? What you did?

Comment: Thanks @noobs. Your `iteration = 0` is outside of the loop but I need inside of the loop. I am also trying. Thanks

Comment: @abuabu is `audio.ended` called on each iteration of for loop?

Comment: Yes, I would like to play audio file one after another. So when one file is finished playing then another file start playing. Thanks.

Comment: @abuabu I've updated my answer. Please let me know if it is working for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reassigning i?

```
for(var i = this.start; i < this.end; i++) {
    var audio = new Audio('some value');
    audio.play();
    if(audio.ended == true) {
        i = this.start;
    }
}
```

Or perhaps you can reassign the currentTime to 0.

```
audio.currentTime = 0 


var audio = null;
var replayed = false;
for(var i = this.start; i < this.end; i++) {
    if( "undefined" == typeof audio.ended || replayed )
        audio = new Audio('some value');
        replayed = false;
    }
    audio.play();
    if(audio.ended == true) {
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
        replayed = true;
    } else {
        --i;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have stay inside loop until the audio play is complete.

Comment: Updated the answer, see if this helps you

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh. Actually I would like to play audio file one after another. I have to use iteration value `i` inside audio file src URL. Thanks.

Comment: I don't need replayed.